# How can I draw C++ concepts in UML class diagram?

Tags: c++, uml, class-diagram, c++-concepts

How would I draw C++ concepts in an UML class diagram?

Specifically, I have the following code:

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept Printable = requires(T a, std::ostream &where) {
    { where << a };
};

template<typename T>
concept Identifiable = requires(T a) {
    { a.getId() } -> std::convertible_to<std::string>;
};

template<typename T>
concept Listable = Identifiable<T> && Printable<T>;
```

and then a class:

```
template<Listable T>
class Liste {
    ...
    void add(T *data);
    ...
}
```

If it were a regular template, I would just put the `T` in a square in the corner of the class. But what about the concepts?

Comment: Not my area but I think you can simply place a constraint along your template binding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [C++ concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) defines constraints on the types associated with a template class:

- Since UML supports [class template](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/class.html#class-template),  you would typically express this [constraints](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/constraint.html) for its parameters, between curly brackets,  either in natural language or in OCL.  The former is perfect at an early design stage.  But you could as well consider to pragmatically express it using the same syntax than C++ instead of natural language, if you need this level of accuracy.
- Alternatively,  you may as well handle the C++ concept as a kind of generic type in UML.   You could then use the concept in a much more readable way in the the type definition of the template parameters in class templates. This would be more convenient to read, and closer to the C++ idea.  The problem is that nothing is foreseen in UML to define such generic types.  You may therefore extend UML with an and-hoc [profile](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/profile.html) to use a `«concept»` [stereotype](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/stereotype.html).  You would then define concepts exactly like classes, define the constraints using the [UML constraints](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/constraint.html),  and use the concepts in UML [class templates](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/class.html#class-template).

Here, how the second approach would look like.  Note the realization [dependency](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/dependency.html?context=class-diagrams) between two concepts:

[image]

Comment: I like the second way. Will probably go with that one.

Comment: Just a little annotation: classes are not defined in diagrams, but they are presented there.

Comment: @qwerty_so Indeed. We could even remind that in a class diagram you don't see any class... only representations of classes ;-)  But this statement would only be a pale mimic of Magritte's famous piece of art, ["the treachery of images"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Treachery_of_Images) ;-)

Comment: Yeah. That's definitely one of my favorites (right after Plato's Cave Allegory).